# Getting Error cannot create symlink Every time

Tags: magento2, less-import

I'm getting following error from a long time and can't get a permanent solution the error is "cannot create symlink error code 1314 Magento 2". The error like symlink _reset.less. Please find the error attachment.

Please, anyone give a perfect solution?[image]

Answer (score 10):

I know this post is old but it may help others. Make sure you open the cmd window as administrator. Right click on CMD then "Run as Administrator" then run the grunt commands and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank u, It's working :)

Comment: I need to tattoo this on my arm as I keep having to google this error and end up here!